# How to create a Polygon around a Linestring as a GeoFence in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, polygon-creation, geofencing

I'm looking for a .net library that will help to create a polygon that I can use as a Geo-fence around a route on a map.

The following image demonstrates the result I'm after. Imagine that this polygon was projected from a line string that defined a route on a map.

[image]

I've not done any GIS mapping work before, so I'm really quite lost even as where or what to look for.

### UPDATE

Ok, I've had a quick look and seem to have something working. The code to generate a polygon as a buffer around the linestring is pretty simple.

```
var line = new LineString(points);
var bufferOp = new BufferOp(line);
var buffer = (Polygon)bufferOp.GetResultGeometry(.00001);
```

But what confuses me now is the distance parameter to GetResultGeomotry. In the above code I'm specifying .00001 as the distance.. this is the only way I could get a reasonable result.

What unit of measure is that?

Comment: Looks like [Buffer](http://nettopologysuite.github.io/html/namespace_net_topology_suite_1_1_operation_1_1_buffer.html) operation from the [NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite) would do the work

Comment: How about DotSpatial?

Comment: @HenWagner thanks for the tip - I've had a look at DotSpatial and updated the question

Comment: Hi @jflood.net, did you find an explanation for the distance factors and units? If I want to draw a buffer of 500 meters, what would be the formula for that distance?