# Route "buffer" algorithm - polygon around a route line

Tags: python, polygon, line, polygon-creation

What is the specification for an algorithm which takes as input an array of coordinates (lat/lon) representing a route on map and a distance argument, outputting the coordinates of a polygon surrounding the route at the given distance?  I am interested in the math required to calculate the polygon points and how things such as line segments which join at a very acute angle are handled.  Related questions which do not produce the answer I am looking for (algorithm specification / equations):

[Buffer along a route](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66562/buffer-along-a-route)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685633/length-buffer-around-polyline

[How to create a Polygon around a Linestring as a GeoFence in C# .NET](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176229/how-to-create-a-polygon-around-a-linestring-as-a-geofence-in-c-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the algorithm used for GIS buffering is called the [Minkowsky Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition).

There are [many](http://www.cgal.org/) [books](http://www.algorist.com/) out there that cover this topic.